# There is a popup, but driver.getWindowHandles() return me only one element which is main window/parent window

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

[Here, I attach the screenshot of that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0up87.png) I'm working on automation. For authentication, a pop-up window is opened. To switch pop-up window, when I use driver.getWindowHandles() it return only one element(window) which is main/parent window. For this, I can't switch to the pop-up window and can't do any operation on the pop-up.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the main window along with popup window. It will help you to get more relevant answers.

Comment: Now, I add the screenshot @SolomonRaja

Comment: This is not a new window; this is probably in a new frame; so try inspecting the elements on this pop-up and backtrack to the frame (if any)